# How to separate API doc to internal functions doc in JSDOC

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have two .js files which represents one module. This module will represent a API to be used with other modules, so i want to well document this API's.

Here's files and functions structure:

```
file1.js
    // Include these functions
    getCLO();      // Should appear in API doc view
    addCLO();      // Should appear in API doc view
    prepareCL();   // Should appear in internal module doc view not in API view

file2.js
    // Include these functions
    getLM();       // Should appear in API doc view
    addLM();       // Should appear in API doc view
    prepareLM();   // Should appear in internal module doc view not in API view
```

When i use JSDOC i get all functions in Global section, which will be good for internal module doc. **But how to select some functions to be documented in API view and how to generate it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use @private or [@access](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-access.html) to have control on which functions are generated